# Delete Unused Languages Automatically

Tags: apt, dpkg, language-support, locale

I used to use an application that would delete the unused locale and language files from apps that I install automatically when installing through apt-get.

I can't seem to find this now and I really need to free up some space.

Does anyone know the name of this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It is called localepurge.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install localepurge
```

Follow the instructions.